# Can I generate LLVM bytecode with Rubinius and run it with lli?

Tags: llvm, bytecode, rubinius

I've tried running `rbx compile` but I am not quite sure what to do with the output. I would like to run it with lli, but I get the following error.

```
$ lli hello.rbc
lli: hello.rbc:2:1: error: expected '=' here
18185007515559028006
^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't run Rubinius byte-compiled code with lli because the .rbc file isn't an LLVM executable. Instead, you run it with a special Rubinius method call that handles pre-compiled bytecode for the Rubinius virtual machine. For example:

```
rbx -I. -e "Rubinius::CodeLoader.require_compiled 'hello'"
```

See [Running Ruby With No Ruby](http://rubini.us/2011/03/17/running-ruby-with-no-ruby/) for more details.